# Display a confirm message

Tags: javascript, asp.net, confirm

Want to display a "confirm" message in my asp.net application, when the window closes, but when the Cancel button is pressed, the page closes, the event is not Canceled.

I tried a different approach: I use

```
event.returnValue = "Message";
```

This approach works (when cancel is pressed, page does not close), but I get the "Message" that I specify plus some other message; "Click Accept or Cancel to cancel" or something similar.

How can I create a message on the client side that only displays the text that I specify?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The confirm message shown when a script attempts to prevent browser close/leaving the page is in part defined by the browser. You can only define *part* of the message.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done as a confirm message is shown when script attempts to change the closing behavior of the page by the browser

Comment: what if I use:
event.returnValue = "Message"; 
Is there a way to define the message?
Cheers

Comment: I don't think so onbeforeunload event will give that confirm box. you can try onload event probably that wont give you this confirm box

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(!confirm("Well?"))
    return "PLEASE STICK AROUND!";
}
```

Note: onbeforeunload fires when the document is unloaded, not the window.  So every redirect will fire the event.  I'm afraid this is the best you can do.